# Excel converts imported from csv numbers to text

Tags: excel, csv, import

when I import the data from csv, I cannot work on it because the excel treats the numbers as a text. When I try to sum them or get the average I get 0 or error becouse there are none number. It changes when i delete the dot '.' in one cell and put i again. That operation changes type of variable to number and it works. But I don't want to change tousends of data in this way. How can I convert it somehow to make i work?
Thanks for every answer.

Comment: This is not usual behavior, however I cannot reproduce your problem from the limited information you have provided. I suggest you read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then edit your question to provide useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use general options selected properly dont import with text format select general format as given in picture.

[image]